# How do I assert the identity of a PyQt5 signal?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-signals

I'm in a situation where I want to assert the identity of a PyQt5 signal. Specifically, I want to check whether the `clicked` signal from a given `QPushButton` object is identical to a signal that is stored in a variable named `signal`. The following snippet illustrates the situation:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton

app = QApplication([])
widget = QPushButton()
signal = widget.clicked

widget.clicked == signal
Out[1]: False

widget.clicked is signal
Out[2]: False

id(widget.clicked) == id(signal)
Out[3]: False
```

As shown, the three comparisons involving `==`, `is`, and `id()` respectively all produce `False`, i.e. they fail to assert the identity of the left-hand and the right-hand argument.

Is there any way to assert that `widget.clicked` and `signal` are referencing the same signal?

Comment: When connecting a button's `clicked` signal, the slot will receive  *all clicks from that button*, not one particular click. So it's not clear what you mean by "the same signal". What exactly do you intend to do with the `signal` variable elsewhere in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signals as entities are created each time you invoke it as they represent a different connection:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

In [3]: app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

In [4]: button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()

In [5]: id(button.clicked)
Out[5]: 140150155639464

In [6]: id(button.clicked)
Out[6]: 140150154507528

In [7]: id(button.clicked)
Out[7]: 140150155640184

In [8]: id(button.clicked)
Out[8]: 140150155640504

In [9]: id(button.clicked)
Out[9]: 140150154510128

In [10]: id(button.clicked)
Out[10]: 140149427454320
```

Therefore if you connect 100 times between the same signal and slot, and when the signal is emitted, the slot will be called 100 times:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

def foo():
    print("clicked")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press me")
    button.show()
    for _ in range(10):
        button.clicked.connect(foo)
    # the click is emulated
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: button.animateClick(500))
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000, app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

```
clicked
clicked
clicked
clicked
clicked
clicked
clicked
clicked
clicked
clicked
```

So it will be impossible to solve your problem directly but I think that your goal is to discriminate which object that emitted the signal that calls the slot since you probably have several objects connected to the same slot, and for that if there is a solution:

#### 1. Using `sender()` method

If the slot belongs to a QObject (or classes derived from QObject as the widgets) then you can use the sender method to obtain the object that emitted the signal.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("button 1")
        self.button_1.clicked.connect(self.foo)
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("button 2")
        self.button_2.clicked.connect(self.foo)
        self.button_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("button 3")
        self.button_3.clicked.connect(self.foo)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.button_1)
        lay.addWidget(self.button_2)
        lay.addWidget(self.button_3)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def foo(self):
        button = self.sender()
        if button is self.button_1:
            print("button_1")
        elif button is self.button_2:
            print("button_2")
        elif button is self.button_3:
            print("button_3")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### 2. Pass the object as an additional parameter

2.1 lambda function

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("button 1")
        self.button_1.clicked.connect(lambda *args, b=self.button_1 : self.foo(b))
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("button 2")
        self.button_2.clicked.connect(lambda *args, b=self.button_2 : self.foo(b))
        self.button_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("button 3")
        self.button_3.clicked.connect(lambda *args, b=self.button_3 : self.foo(b))

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.button_1)
        lay.addWidget(self.button_2)
        lay.addWidget(self.button_3)

    def foo(self, button):
        if button is self.button_1:
            print("button_1")
        elif button is self.button_2:
            print("button_2")
        elif button is self.button_3:
            print("button_3")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

2.1 functools.partial function

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from functools import partial

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("button 1")
        self.button_1.clicked.connect(partial(self.foo, self.button_1))
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("button 2")
        self.button_2.clicked.connect(partial(self.foo, self.button_2))
        self.button_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("button 3")
        self.button_3.clicked.connect(partial(self.foo, self.button_3))

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.button_1)
        lay.addWidget(self.button_2)
        lay.addWidget(self.button_3)

    def foo(self, button):
        if button is self.button_1:
            print("button_1")
        elif button is self.button_2:
            print("button_2")
        elif button is self.button_3:
            print("button_3")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

In my case I prefer to use sender if I can use it, then functools.partial and finally lambda methods

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton

app = QApplication([])

def clickButton(w):
    # Check what you clicked here.                        # <-----
    return print(w.text())

widget  = QPushButton('Button 1')
widget.clicked.connect(lambda : clickButton(widget))

widget2 = QPushButton('Button 2')
widget2.clicked.connect(lambda : clickButton(widget2))

widget.setGeometry(300, 150, 100, 100)
widget.show()

widget2.setGeometry(450, 150, 100, 100)
widget2.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]